# Two Matlab ODE solvers, two different results

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, matlab

I am solving a system of ODEs using Matlab. One particular set of parameters caused the solver to fail, so I worked my way through the different solvers Matlab provides. I was surprised to find that two of the solvers (ode23s and ode23tb) produced completely different, yet reasonable, results. Every other solver failed.

My question: Which one (if any) should I trust and why?

I'm not entirely sure if this is a mathematics question or a programming question, but I suspect it comes to a difference in the numerical methods, hence posting it here.

ode23s:

[image]

ode23tb:

[image]

For reference the ODEs are:
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=-\beta IS+\xi(1-S)+3 \kappa L\\
\frac{dI}{dt}=\beta IS+\alpha IL-\xi I-\gamma I\\
\frac{dR}{dt}=\nu \beta IW+\gamma I - \xi R - 3\kappa R \\
\frac{dL}{dt}=-\alpha IL+3 \kappa W-\xi L -3 \kappa L\\
\frac{dW}{dt}=-\nu \beta IW + 3 \kappa R -\xi W - 3 \kappa W\\$$

With parameters:
$$\alpha=26,
\beta=260,
\kappa=.1,
\gamma=17,
\nu=5,
\xi=0.0125$$

And initial conditions:

$$S_0=.99,
I_0=1-S_0,
R_0=0,
L_0=0,
W_0=0$$

Comment: The last one is the correct one (I checked). It's hard to say why. First thing to do is to tripple check that you applied it correctly (there is always one more bug). Your equation seems to be pretty stiff so this could be the reason (i.e. that the first method might be taking to large steps). You could try increasing the internal accuracy parameters and see if this helps.

Comment: I did suspect that the last one was correct because of stiffness, but couldn't justify why. I'll try what you suggested, but I'm still interested in the ``why" part of this question (if it is answerable)

Comment: Hard to say, the description of the solvers are very similar. I think you need to ask someone who's more familiar with Matlab for this. It might be that someone here knows this, but I think you'll have a better chance at [the Matlab forum](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/).

Comment: Yep, I would try lowering the tolerances and seeing what changes. The algorithms are complicated so it's going to be hard to tell the difference. It could also be that your epidemic is on the edge of taking off or not, so a very small error early on could tip it over the edge and have it take off. Try changing the parameters a bit and seeing if that changes the solutions much.

Comment: I agree with @David . Your numerical trajectory might got too close to boundary of two basins of attraction and two different methods behave differently when they are near it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks a lot like you have (at least one) bifurcation point.

You can perform a stability analysis based on linerization which shows that actually both equilibria have exactly one unstable direction corresponding to an eigenvalue with negative real part.

Thus, if the trajectories from the different solvers are somewhat sufficiently aligned with those unstable directions, this causes them to miss that equilibrium / steady state. Conversely, if they progress in directions more or less aligned with the stable ones, they approach the corresponding equilibrium.
In the context of your system, `ode23s` "finds" thus the stable directions of the $(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ equilibrium or is repelled by the unstable direction of the $\sim (0.0589, 0.0021, 0.7937, 0.0655, 0.0799)$ steady state (or mixture of both).
Converse holds for the `ode23tb` solver.

I attach some Matlab files I used throughout the analysis, including a animation of the trajectories in reduced ($I, L, R + L +W$) space, showing that somewhere around $I \approx L \approx 0, R + L + W \approx 1$ the bifurcation happends.

```
    function f = ODE_System(~, SIRLW)

    % Parameters
    alpha = 26;
    beta  = 260;
    kappa = 0.1;
    k     = 3 * kappa; % Kappa only used after multiplication with 3
    gamma = 17;
    nu    = 5;
    xi    = 0.0125;
    
    S = SIRLW(1); I = SIRLW(2); R = SIRLW(3); L = SIRLW(4); W = SIRLW(5);
    
    f = zeros(5, 1);
    f(1) = -beta * I * S + xi * (1 - S) + k * L;
    f(2) =  beta * I * S + alpha * I * L - xi * I - gamma * I;
    f(3) = nu * beta * I * W + gamma * I - xi * R - k * R;
    f(4) = -alpha * I * L + k * W - xi * L - k * L;
    f(5) = - nu * beta * I * W + k * R - xi * W - k * W;
    end
```

```
    function Df_Dx = Eval_Jacob(SIRLW_eq)
    % Evaluates Jacobian at given point
    
    % Parameters
    alpha = 26;
    beta  = 260;
    kappa = 0.1;
    k     = 3 * kappa; % Kappa only used after multiplication with 3
    gamma = 17;
    nu    = 5;
    xi    = 0.0125;
    
    S_eq = SIRLW_eq(1); I_eq = SIRLW_eq(2); R_eq = SIRLW_eq(3); L_eq = SIRLW_eq(4); W_eq = SIRLW_eq(5);
    
    Df_Dx = [-beta * I_eq - xi, -beta * S_eq,                            0,        k,                      0;
             beta * I_eq,       beta * S_eq + alpha * L_eq - xi - gamma, 0,        alpha * I_eq,           0; 
             0,                 nu * beta * W_eq + gamma,                -xi - k,  0,                      nu * beta * I_eq;
             0,                 -alpha * L_eq,                           0,        -alpha * I_eq - xi - k, 0;
             0,                 -nu * beta * W_eq,                       k,        0,                      -xi - k;         ];
    end
```

```
    clear;
    close all;
    clc;
    
    % Parameters
    alpha = 26;
    beta  = 260;
    kappa = 0.1;
    k     = 3 * kappa; % Kappa only used after multiplication with 3
    gamma = 17;
    nu    = 5;
    xi    = 0.0125;
    
    %% Equilibrium of upper / first plot
    SILRW_Eq_1 = [1; 0; 0; 0; 0];
    Df_Dx      = Eval_Jacob(SILRW_Eq_1);  
    [EVec_Eq_1, EVal_Eq_1] = eigs(Df_Dx); % Shows one eigenvalue (whose real part) > 0 => Unstable equilibrium
    
    %% Equilibrium of lower / second plot
    tspan   = [0, 100];
    S_0     = 0.99;
    SILRW_0 = [S_0; 1 - S_0; 0; 0; 0];
    [t_tb, SILRW_tb] = ode23tb(@ODE_System, tspan, SILRW_0);
    [t_s,  SILRW_s]  = ode23s( @ODE_System, tspan, SILRW_0);
     
    % Show that this values lead indeed to (more or less) an equilibrium:
    SILRW_Eq_2 = SILRW_tb(end, :)';
    t_dummy = 42;
    disp(ODE_System(t_dummy, SILRW_Eq_2)); % Not really 0 yet
    
    % Other way of obtaining this equilibrium: Solve eqs. numerically with ode solver outcome as start value
    options = optimoptions('fsolve', 'Display', 'iter');
    fun = @(x) ODE_System(t_dummy, x);
    SILRW_Eq_2 = fsolve(fun, SILRW_Eq_2, options);
    % Check values of RHS again, they are now machine precision:
    disp(ODE_System(t_dummy, SILRW_Eq_2));
    
    Df_Dx     = Eval_Jacob(SILRW_Eq_2);  
    [EVec_Eq_2, EVal_Eq_2] = eigs(Df_Dx); % Shows one eigenvalue with real part > 0 => Unstable equilibrium
    
    %% Investigate trajectories
    % Bundle RLW into one variable (leaves one with 3 variables which can be plotted)
    SI_Bundled_tb = [SILRW_tb(:, 1), SILRW_tb(:, 2), SILRW_tb(:, 3) + SILRW_tb(:, 4) + SILRW_tb(:, 5)];
    SI_Bundled_s  = [SILRW_s(:, 1),  SILRW_s(:, 2),  SILRW_s(:, 3)  + SILRW_s(:, 4)  + SILRW_s(:, 5)];
    
    for i = 1:length(t_s)
      plot3(SI_Bundled_s(i, 1), SI_Bundled_s(i, 2), SI_Bundled_s(i, 3), '-rx');
      xlabel('S');
      ylabel('I');
      zlabel('R + L + W');
      title('Trajectories. Red: ode23 S, Blue: ode23 TB');
      hold all;
      pause(0.1);
    end
    
    for i = 1:length(t_tb) / 3 % All the action done by then
      plot3(SI_Bundled_tb(i, 1), SI_Bundled_tb(i, 2), SI_Bundled_tb(i, 3), '-bo', 'Displayname', 'ode23_TB');
      hold all;
      pause(0.1);
    end
```

Comment: This is a really good analysis, and in line with what I came to suspect. I tried out your matlab code and it failed for me when setting `optimoptions` (I have 2020a). I'll try to work out the problem when I get some time. Other than that, it would be great if you could post some kind of bifurcation diagram or similar

Comment: Actually, quickly found out that it's because fsolve is apparently part of the optimisation toolbox that I don't have access to